# JasperReports Server: How do I send a Array of data throug a URL

Tags: url, jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

I want to send a array of ID's of unknown length through a URL (array can contain anything from 1 to 15 ID's)

MORE DETAILS:

Currently I am sending Parameters through like this

```
...&date=2012/02/02&VEFactorSelection=3&nameType=2
```

This works fine for Variables that can only have a single value (String, Int, Date etc.)

But I now need to send a array through and be able to read it again

How do I do this?

MORE INFO:
The data is being sent from one report to the drill down report (*JasperReports Server 5.0.1*)

I'm using *iReport 5.0.0* for reports creation

Comment: In iReport, when you define the hyperlink parameters, have you had any luck switching the Parameter Class Name from string to collection?

Comment: I can send the Collection just by useing "+ "&campusAndFaculty=" + $P{campusAndFaculty}" and it comes out like this "&campusAndFaculty=[111, 113, 115]#"

But it doesn't seem like the report is reading it, I get No Data